# How to prevent hibernate from creating a proxy

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy

I have a tricky problem with hibernate using more queries than necessary for a simple findAll call. In my model there is two entities Parent and Child with oneToMany association;

**Parent**

```
class Parent{
    @id
    private long id;

    //unique
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OperatorAttribute> children;
}
```

**Child**

```
class Child{
    @id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_code", referencedColumnName = "code")
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY) // here i'm trying to tell hibernate to create no proxy and just ignore the field but no luck :/
    public Parent parent;
}
```

The problem is that whenever I try to fetch the list of child using `childRepository.findAll()` from the database, hibernate make N+1 select query, why ?

I think this may be the explanation for that: IMHO when Hibernate populate the child object, he tries to create a proxy for the parent field, 
and for that he needs the id of the parent row, which should normally be the foreign key in the child table, but in my case the `#fk` isn't binded to the primary key of the `Parent` table but to a unique column (plz don't ask me why) so in order to populate the id he needs to do an additional select query just to initialize the proxy of the parent field.

So my **question** is how to prevent Hibernate from creating a proxy for the parent field.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add the code where you are calling the findAll repository method?

Comment: I don't think it's relevant but I use querydsl
 `new HibernateQuery(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).from(qChild).list(qChild)`

Comment: According to [JavaDoc `NO_PROXY`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/LazyToOneOption.html#NO_PROXY) option requires [bytecode enhancement](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html) and that Hibernate will "_fall back to `PROXY` if the class is not enhanced_". Is it enabled in your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The proxy needs the `@Id` of the proxied entity (this way it could be made sure that it could be find). As soon you define the `LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY` it tells the system to [give back the real object](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/LazyToOneOption.html#NO_PROXY). And this is what happens here. What you get mapped on the result is not a proxy, because with this annotation you explicitly disabled it so you have to get the real object.

Based on the mapping provided you cannot ignore the field because You'll loose the information what was is the `Parent` on the `Child`. So with this kind of setup you'll always need to read the `parent`.

If this field is not needed at all in a specific area, you can create some other mappings to the same table. But be careful! This could introduce a load of other cache related problems.